# Can't restore SQL Server database to another server

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to migrate databases from an old, dying server, to the new one.

All over the internet, I found two handy [scripts](http://andrewmorgan.ie/2011/12/backup-and-restore-sql-databases-using-powershell/) by Andrew Morgan, for saving and restoring databases. The backup part works well; I get my `db.bak` on my local pc by sharing the folder over the network and having the script backup the db to the unc path.

Unfortunately, the restoring part won't work, and I don't know why (and my senior DEV doesn't know either, and he's the one knowing SQL aorund here).

I'm calling it this way:

```
Restore-SQLdatabase -SQLServer "NEWSERVER\MSSQLSERVER" -SQLDatabase "DBToMigrate" -Path "C:\Backup\DBToMigrate.bak" -SQLusername "sa" -SQLpassword "IMAPLAINTEXTPASSWORD"
```

`sa` has complete power over the database.

It fails with the following message:

> Attempting to connect to the Specified SQL server: Success
>   WARNUNG: An Exception was caught while restoring the database!
>   WARNUNG: Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "ExecuteNonQuery" mit 0 Argument(en):  "Incorrect syntax near '‘'.
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon."
>   WARNUNG: attempting to recover the database

The part in question is:

```
ALTER DATABASE $SQLDatabase
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

RESTORE DATABASE $SQLDatabase
FROM DISK = '$path'
WITH REPLACE
```

When it gets executed, the scipt gets the exception.

I tried putting a `CREATE DATABASE $SQLDatabase` in front of the `ALTER` part, but then it says something along the lines of "that database name already exists", after creating that db.

Also, when omitting the altering part and changing that part to

```
RESTORE DATABASE $SQLDatabase FROM DISK = '$path' WITH REPLACE
```

It says something about the database files, giving me the path on the old server (which I'd like to be completely irrelevant, but it seems there may be my next problem), cannot be found (of course, since I'm on my local machine now, which doesn't have those).

I'm doing it with a script, because there are around 15 databases we need to migrate, and also because I want to learn how to do this stuff without just using the SSMS wizard.

**Update:** I changed the apostrophes to normal ones, that was indeed the mistake. Now I just need to get the file name of the db files so I can `MOVE` them to the new server.

Comment: `"Incorrect syntax near '‘'` - -if you copy/pasted the scripts replace any fancy quotes (`‘`) with `'` - although using the SSMS Restore tools is probably a much better idea.

Comment: Why do you create database just before the restore? You need to put database in single_user if it's live database and you need to disconnect all the users. Don't create, just restore your database from your backup and write new paths for the files

Comment: @AlexK.thanks, that was indeed the (first) mistake!

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to write a new destinations to your files, you can check the syntax of RESTORE here: [RESTORE Statements (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql#restoring_full_db)

And your code will be like this:

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012  
   FROM AdventureWorksBackups  
   WITH MOVE 'AdventureWorks2012_Data' TO   
'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\NewAdvWorks.mdf',   
      MOVE 'AdventureWorks2012_Log'   
TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\NewAdvWorks.ldf';
```

Comment: So without `ALTER` before that? Above, you said I should put it in `single_user` mode (which I do right now anyway). Also: I can't directly point to the backups, as I'm running the script from my local pc, to restore a bak, from a database lying on a pc that occasionally works. Although I guess `FROM DISK = '$path'`works, otherwise somebody would have told me about it.

Comment: You are restoring to a new server, right? So these databases do not exist yet. So you have no need to disconnect users, you even have no need to create databases before restore. You just restore the existing backups specifying where to put mdf/ldf, the new database will be created for you

Comment: Can I get the filenames (`AdventureWorks2012_data` and `..._log`) with a query too? Our files are usually called `dbName` and `dbName_log`, but I actually found a case where the logical name is something else, so I'd like to automate that part too.

Comment: Yes you can use RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'your_backup_file_full_path', see https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/109/sql-server-restore-filelistonly/